# object automatically movement in sdl

Tags: c, sdl

how can I move an object in sdl with press one key from a keyboard, then the object move automatically?
for example, I need to move a bullet from a tank in the game (alter tank), so I press a key then the bullet should move automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, if you want to make something like this, what you'd do is use a [game loop](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html). In broad strokes, you define functions that check what things need to be updated (the player, enemies, bullets, items, etc), and then update each one.

In this case, you want, for example, an array of bullets. You animate each one every frame. When you press a button, you add a new bullet to the array. Once that bullet is in the array, it will 'move by itself'. If that makes sense.

Answer (score -2):

Just use the SDL events: https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/guideinputkeyboard.html

Wait for the required keyboard event and call the function that moves the bullet.

This example is from the doc and is slightly adapted.

```
SDL_Event event;


/* Poll for events. SDL_PollEvent() returns 0 when there are no  */
/* more events on the event queue, our while loop will exit when */
/* that occurs.                                                  */
while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) ){
    /* We are only worried about SDL_KEYDOWN and SDL_KEYUP events */
    switch( event.type ){
    case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        printf( "Key press detected\n" );
        break;

    case SDL_KEYUP:
        printf( "Key release detected\n" );
        move_bullet(); // create your handler here
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```